# PHP returns results in an ugly single line

Tags: php, json

I want php to return the $users not in a single line as:

```
 [{"id":1,"name":"xxxx","email":"xxxx@yyyy.com","email_verified_at":null,"password":"xyzxyz","remember_token":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]
```

I would like to have it in the following manner:

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"xxxx",
        "email":"xxxx@yyyy.com",
        "email_verified_at":null,
        "password":"xyzxyz",
        "remember_token":null,
        "created_at":null,
        "updated_at":null
    }
]
```

How can I make that happen, please?

Comment: Formatting has never been a strong point of PHP. How are you currently outputting this data; is it console/command line output, HTML web page, file dump, etc?

Comment: I am assuming that is using `json_encode()`, if not the dupe can be removed.

Comment: It is console/command line output.